# Reactjs how to call my subcategory function for only specific id of each items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Right now my all category getting clicked if I click on any single category. How I can prevent to show all category. see the screenshot [image]

here I am clicking only electronic category but others category and sub category showing.

here is my code:

my list of data

```
const data =[
  {
    "id":1, 
    "main_category": "Electronic",
    "sub_category": "mobile",
  },
  {
    "id":2, 
    "main_category": "Pet",
    "sub_category": "Home pet",
  }
  ,
  {
    "id":3, 
    "main_category": "Furniture",
    "sub_category": "kitchen",
  }
]
```

my code start from here...

```
const PostAds = () => {
  const[showsubcat,setShowSubCat] = useState(false)
   
   let subcategory=(()=>{
              
             setShowSubCat(prev=>!prev)
       }) 
   
   


  return (
    <>{data.map((data)=>{
                         return(
                          <>
                           
                          <li class="list-group-item" id="category" onClick={subcategory} >{data.main_category}</li>
                            {showsubcat && 
                          <li><i class="las la-angle-right" id="sub_category"></i> {data.sub_category}</li>
                          }
                          
                          </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const[showsubcat,setShowSubCat] = useState(false)
```

This is setting a global state that is then re used on every category item that you have. Even though you have different `<li>` tags they're all using the same showsubcat. I would recommend make a different component each li and then map that in your parent component.

```
const PostSingleAd = ({ data, itemOpenedId, setItemOpenedId }) => {
  const [showsubcat, setShowSubCat] = useState(false);
  let subcategory = () => {
    setShowSubCat((prev) => !prev);
    setItemOpenedId(data.id);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (itemOpenedId !== data.id) {
      setShowSubCat(false);
    }
  }, [itemOpenedId]);
  return (
    <>
      <li class="list-group-item" id="category" onClick={subcategory}>
        {data.main_category}
      </li>
      {showsubcat && (
        <li>
          <i class="las la-angle-right" id="sub_category"></i>{" "}
          {data.sub_category}
        </li>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
const PostAds = () => {
  const [itemOpenedId, setItemOpenedId] = useState();
  return data.map((data) => (
    <PostSingleAd
      data={data}
      itemOpenedId={itemOpenedId}
      setItemOpenedId={setItemOpenedId}
    />
  ));
};
```

Comment: thanks it's working but can I can I make previous item stats false if click on new item

Comment: Without using state management tool like redux you could lift the state up like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-lucy-efmwx9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a  loooot. Can you please explain little bit your code so othres people can het help from your answerer